# Using Component styles results in conflicting html/body styles

Tags: angular, sass

I have two components in my Angular 2 app and they each define different styles in SASS files. Unfortunately it appears that both components' styles are being loaded for both components, resulting in conflicting html and body styles.

My component definitions looks like this:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'signup',
    directives: [RouterOutlet, RouterLink],
    styles: [require('../sass/signup.scss').toString()],
    template: require('./signup.component.html')
})
```

and

```
@Component({
  selector: 'signin',
  directives: [RouterOutlet, RouterLink],
  styles: [require('../sass/signin.scss').toString()],
  template: require('./signin.component.html')
})
```

The stylesheets look like this:

```
// signup.scss
html, body {
    height:100%;
    background-color: #eaeaea;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
}
```

and

```
// signin.scss
html, body {
    height:100%;
    background-color: #373746;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
}
```

The backround-color of both components is `#373746`.

Any thoughts? I could easily create two separate `<div>`s with with ids or classes but that would be a workaround; as my application grows I don't really want to be keeping track of which styles are defined for which components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add `styles` inside your ng2 components, this is for styling them, not the entire page (what you do with selectors `html` & `body`).

You can do like this:

```
  @Component({
      selector: 'signup',
      directives: [RouterOutlet, RouterLink],
      styles: ['
        signup {
          background-color: red;
        }
      '],
      template: '<p>I\'m the signup with red background!</p>'
  })

  @Component({
      selector: 'signin',
      directives: [RouterOutlet, RouterLink],
      styles: ['
        signin {
          background-color: blue;
        }
      '],
      template: '<p>I\'m the signin with blue background!</p>'
  })
```

Comment: Well my components are centred vertically and horizontally on the page, and this suggestion only colours the background of the component, not the whole page. How can I change the background colour between pages?

Comment: I just write this example to show you how `styles` inside ng2 components must apply only to them. Then you can add a css file applying to the whole page or add another component containing `signup` and `signin` and styles applying to both. If you want more details, send a plunker with you specific case.

Comment: Thanks @bertrandg. I will make the components full screen to get around this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could always give your body an id and then in the relevant component typescript files change the background css attribute with:

```
ngOnInit () {
    document.getElementById('body').style.background-color = "#eaeaea";
}
```